# Embed html5 video player url to facebook

Tags: facebook, iframe, html5-video

I have an html page where I have only html5 video player. When i embed that page in iframe it works perfectly but when i tried to post that iframe on Facebook it does not render video from iframe.

Can you guys let me know what html is required to render my webpage iframe on facebook.

Comment: There is no way to render an iframe on Facebook.

Comment: Not in news feed at least ... page tab apps are still a thing though. (But I rather doubt that's what you actually wanted.)

Comment: I just want the same thing happened if you embed youtube videos on facebook, it shows the player with play mark and the video image. If you click on that it will redirect to youtube.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.